# How can I add a border to the Promoted Link tiles?

Tags: 2013, promoted-links

Currently I am using SharePoint 2013's Promoted Links to create Windows-8-like-tiles I was wondering if there was some CSS that could be done so that these tiles could have borders around the images instead of me editing the photos so that they have a border.

For example:

[image: Example of the tiles that I want a border for.]

Now how would I make it so that these would have a black border around the rim of the tiles so that the white image background wouldn't blend in with the white background of the page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by embedding CSS on the page targeting the `ms-tileview-tile-content` class.

Essentially you can add a Script Editor Web Part on the page, and include the following code within.

`<style>
.ms-tileview-tile-content {
  border: 2px solid black; 
}
</style>`

Comment: Wonderful. That did the trick right quick. :D Thank you!

Comment: Just let it be known - whenever I did this with the "Embed Code" it would work but when I hit save it would delete or cause the tiles to be unable to be seen on the page. This was fixed by instead inserting the code above in a content editor web part.